# Quickbooks Online Error

Tags: php, quickbooks-online

When I attempt to connect to QBO via the Consolibyte package I downloaded I get an error.

Error Code: internal_error

Message: Error getting application from request token

I have set up the config.php file as directed in the instructions and even got to the point of authorizing the application with Quickbooks but now when I navigate to the page it indicates that I am not logged in and when I click the "Connect to QuickBooks" button on the index.php page I get the error above. I'm not familiar enough with the process to know where to start troubleshooting this problem and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would start by posting your config data (it should all be dev data, so none of it is sensitive) so that we can see what you're actually doing. Also, did you check your PHP error log?

Comment: Also -- are you 100% positive you updated your token, key, and secret in the config.php file to the correct values from your app?